# Shuffle Class Instances

Tags: android

My program is a quiz which asks questions for US States
I create three instances of a class say State

```
State st1 = new State();
State st2 = new State();
State st3 = new State();
```

like it asks a question about a state what is capital of st1.name
and line below that it gives 3 option

```
String Builder sb;
sb.append("What is Capital of "+st1.name+"\n");
sb.append("\n"+st1.capital);
sb.append("\n"+st2.capital);
sb.append("\n"+st3.capital);
mainText.setText(sb.toString);
```

now the problem is every time it comes up with correct answer in first line...
how do i avoid that ?

Comment: I have no idea what the question is. "Every time it comes up with correct answer in first line". What does that mean? What is the correct answer? The code doesn't tell us much.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt add much details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the correct answer in a random spot using Java's `Random` class

`Random.nextInt(3)` will give you a random number between 0 and 2.  Put your correct answer into an array of size 3 at location and put the two wrong answers in the remaining locations.  Then loop through that array and `sb.append(array[i]);` (i between 0 and 2) to get your random ordering of state capitals.

Comment: Call the `Random.nextInt(3)` every time you load up a new question.

Comment: I had to put in a loop and make it sure keep looping till all three created numbers are different.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ArrayList the pull the objects out randomly.

**This code is totally untested**, but I don't think it's too far off...

This will (theoretically) list the answers in totally random order.

```
ArrayList<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();
Random rand;
states.add(new State());
states.add(new State());
states.add(new State());

sb.append("What is Capital of "+states.get(0).name+"\n");
int randomNum = 0;
while (states.size() > 0) {
    randomNum = rand.nextInt(1 - states.size() + 1);   
    sb.append("\n"+states.get(randomNum).capital);
    states.remove(randomNum)
}

mainText.setText(sb.toString);
```